# SAN based storage with chronicle queue

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I started using chronicle-queue a few days back, and i was going through its [documentation](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue).

> Chronicle Queue does not support operating off any network file
>   system, be it NFS, AFS, SAN-based storage or anything else. The reason
>   for this is those file systems do not provide all the required
>   primitives for memory-mapped files Chronicle Queue uses.

When i tried writing and reading from a SAN mounted location, i was able to do it.

Can someone explain what does exactly mean by '*chronicle does not support operating off any network file system*.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever access a SAN or NFS drive from one machine, this should work.  However, if the you access it from two machines, you are likely to see an inconsistent state as the order in which pages are flushed to the underlying storage is not reliable.

For fail over and distribution of queues, we recommend using Chronicle Queue Enterprise.